# Написать скрипт sitemap.php, который будет генерировать sitemap.xml

Tags: xml, php

Есть задача - написать скрипт sitemap.php, который будет генерировать карту сайта, вида, sitemap.xml.

Вид файла sitemap.xml стандартный:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
#здесь всё что генерируется вашим циклом#
</urlset>
```

Внутри тэгов <urlset></urlset> нужно вывести все страницы сайта http://www.tehnodar.kh.ua/. Например:

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.tehnodar.kh.ua/</loc>
</url>
```

И так далее, вывести все страницы сайта.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм написания данного php скрипта, без подключения к базе данных MySQL. Заранее спасибо.

Есть идея попробовать так:

```
(array)$site = scandir("http://www.tehnodar.kh.ua/");
$fp = fopen("sitemap.xml", "w");
print_r($site);
fputs($fp, $site);
fclose($fp);
```

Это супер упрощенный вариант, скажите, он имеет право на жизнь? Если элементы массива $site перебрать в цикле $site[i], как их потом все сохранить в файл sitemap.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша идея бредовая :)
Вы пытаетесь открыть HTML текст(именно его получит функция) как директорию.

Есть [скрипт](http://enarion.net/tools/phpsitemapng/), который делает что вы хотите.

Вообще подключение к MySQL может понадобиться для того что бы ускорить процесс генерации карты сайта. Если у вас более менее статичный сайт с парой сотен статей - можете не заморачиваться.